# How to write roles and policies in Hashicorp Vault using a pipeline

Tags: gitlab, hashicorp-vault, gitlab-omnibus

I am using Hashicorp Vault for managing and storing my secrets. And using Gitlab as a CI/CD pipeline to read those secrets. Using this documentation https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/authenticating-with-hashicorp-vault/,  I am able to read the secrets using JWT.
But those secrets/roles/policies I had already configured from Vault CLI

What i want to know is if there is a way to create policies and roles using directly from the pipeline. For example 1st step is to create the role like this -

```
$ vault write auth/jwt/role/myproject-production - <<EOF
{
  "role_type": "jwt",
  "policies": ["myproject-production"],
  "token_explicit_max_ttl": 60,
  "user_claim": "user_email",
  "bound_claims_type": "glob",
  "bound_claims": {
    "project_id": "42",
    "ref_protected": "true",
    "ref_type": "tag",
    "ref": "auto-deploy-*"
  }
}
EOF
```

Here you can see I have attached a policy `myproject-production` to this role which will be created like this -

```
$ vault policy write myproject-production - <<EOF
# Policy name: myproject-production
#
# Read-only permission on 'secret/data/myproject/production/*' path
path "secret/data/myproject/production/*" {
  capabilities = [ "read" ]
}
EOF
```

How do i perform these 2 steps from a pipeline after Authentication happens successfully from Vault.?
Right now what i am doing is when a new user comes in, I go and create `policy` and `roles` for him and the same the user uses in the pipeline to read the secrets.

Comment: Did you get information on this?

Comment: Have you tried using the vault api using curl inside the pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could do something like as follows?

```py
import argparse
import json

def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Generate JSON structure for a project ID")
    parser.add_argument('--project-id', required=True, help='Project ID')
    return parser.parse_args()

def generate_json_structure(project_id):
    data = {
        "role_type": "jwt",
        "policies": ["myproject-production"],
        "token_explicit_max_ttl": 60,
        "user_claim": "user_email",
        "bound_claims_type": "glob",
        "bound_claims": {
            "project_id": project_id,
            "ref_protected": "true",
            "ref_type": "tag",
            "ref": "auto-deploy-*"
        }
    }
    return json.dumps(data, indent=4)

def main():
    args = parse_args()
    json_output = generate_json_structure(args.project_id)
    print(json_output)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```